Unable to modify row height and picture aspect ratio and height
Trying to open an Excel sheet, change a row's height, then select a picture, change it's aspect ratio to false and then change it's height.  Can't seem to get the syntax correct.
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set myWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(sFileName)
appExcel.Visible = True
Set myWorkSheet = myWorkbook.WorkSheets(myWorkbook.ActiveSheet.NAME)
myWorkSheet.Range("Q3").value = 'test'
myWorkSheet.Range("6:6").RowHeight = 406

' this does not work
  myWorkSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 33")).Select
  myWorkSheet.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
  myWorkSheet.ShapeRange.Height = 409**
' the above does not work

myWorkbook.Save
myWorkbook.Close True
appExcel.qUIT
Set appExcel = Nothing
Set myWorkbook = Nothing

Tells me Object does not support this property or method for this statement:
myWorkSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 33")).Select


With  myWorkSheet.Shapes("Picture 33"): .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse: .Height = 409: End With

See How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA.

Simply avoid Select and use With and reference the name of shape as index name:
With myWorkSheet.Shapes("Picture 33")
  .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
  .Height = 409
End With

